# Can't find a recommendation for some classroom PC management software

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, specific-answer

There must be an answer on Software Recommendations, because I have seen it before, and I even evaluated it in a virtual environment a while ago (too long obviously). I can't find it any more.

It is for managing PCs in a class room. The teacher could decide whether to

- lock the screen or
- show a presentation or
- let the pupils work with some pre-defined software or
- let them do whatever stuff

The tool itself must have been [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis) or [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source), run [offline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) and on [windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), but the question might not have been tagged as such.

IMHO, I upvoted the question and answer (if someone can build a SEDE query or whatever).

I am already trying special search terms such as `score:1` (because I upvoted) and `answers:1` (because there must be an answer).

**It would be great if someone could help me find that product again.**

I have tried the following search terms (and more, before I started documenting what I do):

- `classroom answers:1`
- `class room answers:1`
- `pc management answers:1`
- `lecture answers:1 score:1`
- `[parental-control] answers:1`

It is not one of the following questions/answers:

- [Are there any free or relatively cheap remote classroom software applications?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/are-there-any-free-or-relatively-cheap-remote-classroom-software-applications) (I am not looking for remote classrooms, just a local onsite classroom)
- [Collaboration platform with restricted fields / roles for school reports](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/collaboration-platform-with-restricted-fields-roles-for-school-reports)

It seems it's not in my [bookmarks](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/1935/thomas-weller?tab=bookmarks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember that one: It was even cross-platform and could be used for Linux as well. Luckily I've bookmarked it: [Veyon](https://github.com/veyon/veyon). Now let's see where that Q&A is… Here you go:

[Teaching tools (looking for a program to control what the students are doing in real time)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/71629/185)